# Way to jump to previous / next blank line in Atom?

Tags: atom-editor

I find it useful when navigating a document to be able to move to the previous / next blank line. In Emacs I can do this with Ctrl-up or Ctrl-down. Is there a way to do this in Atom, either with a keymap and/or a package?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this type of navigation is built in to Atom, but it's called 'move to the beginning of the previous paragraph' or 'move to the beginning of the next paragraph'. You can map these functions to keystrokes by placing the following in your keymaps.cson file:

`'ctrl-up': 'editor:move-to-beginning-of-previous-paragraph'
  'ctrl-down': 'editor:move-to-beginning-of-next-paragraph'`